# Querying a string in lucene

Tags: .net, lucene

I am using Lucene for .net.
I have the following document with field and the value is like "5 1 You love banana 5 2 Hello"
How can I query so that it will be a result when I query "5 1" & "banana"?

I am using StandardAnalyzer and the field is analyzed.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the test value is the default search field, you could write a query like `+"5 1" +banana` or alternately `"5 1" AND banana` (though I don't like the Lucene AND/OR/NOT syntax personally)

If it's not the default field, just preface your terms with the search field, such as: `+textfield:"5 1" +textfield:banana`

Lucene standard query syntax is documented pretty well here:
[Version 3.6](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_1/queryparsersyntax.html) Or 
[Version 4.0](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#package_description)